# Google Apps Script for Calendar: searchfilter?

Tags: google-apps-script, enums, google-calendar-api

I am trying to write a Google Apps Script for Google Calendar that automatically declines any invitations where there is no description.

I am using the [getEvents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEvents(Date,Date,Object)) call to retrieve events within a certain window, but I'd also like to filter that to include only events with the status INVITED. I've written something that works, but only when I check my status with getMyStatus. No matter how I tried to use the searchFilter with CalendarApp.GuestStatus.Invited I could not retrieve events with that option passed. Any suggestions?

Here's my working code.

```
function processInvites() {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("mycalendar@google.com");
  var now = new Date();
  var then = new Date(now.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
  var events = [];

  var loopEvents = calendar.getEvents(now, then);

  if(loopEvents.length > 0){
    for(j in loopEvents){
      if(loopEvents[j].getMyStatus() == CalendarApp.GuestStatus.INVITED){
        //if this event has no notes
        if(loopEvents[j].getDescription() == ""){
          loopEvents[j].setMyStatus(CalendarApp.GuestStatus.NO);
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function processInvites() {

    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("yourcalendar@google.com"),
        now = Date(),
        then = new Date(now.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));

    cal.getEvents(now, then).forEach(function(event) {

        if (event.getMyStatus() == CalendarApp.GuestStatus.INVITED && event.getDescription() == "") {

            event.setMyStatus(CalendarApp.GuestStatus.NO);

        }

    });

}
```